# Is there a best practice to store persistent data for a shell script?

Tags: shell

I have an alias named `homework` that cd's me into a directory that I wanna do homework in. I have my `homework directory` persist across sessions by writing it to a file: `~/.homework` as I've seen other applications do similar (but not identical!) things: (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.ssh`, `~/.vim`, `~/.gitconfig`, and `~/.npm`, to name a few).

However, some of these files are scripts to run on startup, some are config files, and others are directories containing all sorts of stuff.

I've also read that you should be using `/etc/` for this type of stuff (`/etc/sudoers`, `/etc/manpath`, `/etc/hosts`).

My question is: **is there an accepted best practice for a certain location on my computer to store persistent data for shell scripts or tiny little aliases like the one I have?** It feels wrong to throw everything in my home directory, but it also feels wrong to put something this trivial in my `/etc` folder.

Binaries go in `*/bin`, special files that correspond to devices go in `/dev`, config stuff goes in `/etc`, temporary files go in `/tmp`. I know I can get away with moving my `~/.homework` file anywhere, but I don't like practicing bad practices out of ignorance!

> For reference, here's how my alias works:
>
> ```
> $cat ~/.homework
> /long/path/name/foo/bar/project-4
>
> $ alias homework
> alias homework='cd $(cat ~/.homework)'
> ```

edit: Since this question was put on hold as opinion-based, I'm assuming that there's no clear best-practice on where to store stuff like this. I suppose that "The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from".

From now on, I'm going to put all my tiny config files in a `~/.config` folder.

Comment: your `~/.homework` file just contains a single line with a directory path in it?

Comment: Additionally this question is exceedingly more verbose than it needs to be.

Comment: @dsstorefile:  There is absolutely no reason for him to explain to us how `~/.bashrc` and various other config files are stored (he actually mistakes a bunch of directories for files anyway).  There is no reason to explain (incorrectly) where binaries go, etc.  Disagree all you want but this question could definitely be thoroughly asked in one paragraph max.

Comment: I coulda asked more concisely: "Where *should* I store persistent data from a command line utility". But then people might interpret it as "where *can* I store...", the answer of which would be anywhere. I don't just want an answer to "where *should* I store...", but I also wanna know why, the historical or standard reasons for placing data there.

Comment: @Jesse_b yeah, in this version only 1 line. In other versions it's had 2 or 3 (or up to n) lines, and I've selected them using `cat ~/.hw | head -${1} | tail -1`, and modified them using `awk`. It seems like a waste to use a whole file on just 1 line!!

Comment: Storing your homework directory in an environmental variable may be an option as well.  Keeps you from needing a new file altogether.

Comment: @Jesse_b That would work,... but I also like being able to easily set it (and having a few "bookmarked" directories). I don't wanna have my `set_work` function change my ~/.bashrc, that seems like bad practice. Currently, my `set_work` function is simply an alias: `echo "$(pwd)" > ~/.homework`

Comment: I could source a config file in my `bashrc` that exported all my config variables, but then I'm having the same issue: where would I place the config file!?! Now that I know, I would put it in `~/.config`!!

Comment: I do not see why this question should be closed. It is certainly not a question with mainly opinion based answers (the right answer is "Do what you like in your home directory; XDG has some suggestions. Other than that there is the Linux FHS.")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're only storing a single file for a personal alias, putting it in `~` is totally fine. There's an XDG Base Directory Specification that says configuration files should go in `~/.config`, but that's up to you. After all, it's *your* home folder! If the path doesn't change often, consider hardcoding it into the alias instead of keeping it in a separate file.

`/etc` is for system-wide configuration files, while `~/.config` is for the user. You're close about where system binaries can go (`/bin`), but also note that user binaries can go in `~/bin`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I'm going to make myself a `~/.config` folder for all the small tinkerings like this that I'm messing with. I love having a `~/bin`, because after putting it in my PATH it lets me tab-complete all my scripts!